# Flink json serialization timezone issue

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I use `JsonRowSerializationSchema` to serialize Flink's Row into JSON. I SQL timestamp serialization has timezone issues.

```
  val row = new Row(1)
  row.setField(0, new Timestamp(0))

  val tableSchema = TableSchema
    .builder
    .field("c", DataTypes.TIMESTAMP(3).bridgedTo(classOf[Timestamp]))
    .build

  val serializer = JsonRowSerializationSchema.builder()
    .withTypeInfo(tableSchema.toRowType)
    .build()

  println(new String(serializer.serialize(row)))
```

> {"c":"1969-12-31T16:00:00Z"}

I see it uses `PST`(local time zone) to interpret timestamp, but then output `UTC`(see `Z` in output)

If I do `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))`, then it prints `{"c":"1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"}`. My timestamps are created for UTC time, and I want Flink to interpret them as UTC.

I am checking the Flink implementation, following two methods are in action.

```
    private JsonNode convertLocalDateTime(ObjectMapper mapper, JsonNode reuse, Object object) {
        return mapper.getNodeFactory()
            .textNode(RFC3339_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT.format((LocalDateTime) object));
    }

    private JsonNode convertTimestamp(ObjectMapper mapper, JsonNode reuse, Object object) {
        Timestamp timestamp = (Timestamp) object;
        return convertLocalDateTime(mapper, reuse, timestamp.toLocalDateTime());
    }
```

It looks like the implementation is hardcoded, is there any way to tell Flink to use `UTC` without changing the system time?

Answer (score 1):

The `java.sql.Timestamp` is very problematic because it depends on a time zone. This is why we replaced it with the new `java.time.*` classes in the new Table/SQL type system.

We recommend that all Flink JVMs are configured in UTC time zone for the outdated implementation.

For Table/SQL, we use the new `org.apache.flink.formats.json.JsonRowDataSerializationSchema` but this works on internal data structures. I would recommend to just copy the source code of `JsonRowSerializationSchema` and implement the format as you need it. Or use the Jackson library directly which would avoid dealing with `TypeInformation` at all.